# iOS Powerpoint Viewer trouble

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, quicklook

I want to implement a PowerPoint viewer in my application. I tried to use Quick Look Framework. But it doesn't support transition animations and full screen.

Can someone help me to implement these two things.

I've also tried to open the presentation in web view.